# How to split comma separated value and insert as a new row with same data

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called product.in that table i am storing epfno as comma sepatred value.but right now i want split epf no and insert as a separate row with same data.how can 1 do that?

example

```
Tag No  Epfno   Department  Weight  In Time         Out Time
82922   D1292,D1132 other2  36.03   5/2/2016 8:18   5/2/2016 8:18
82879   D1258,D1048 other2  30.36   5/2/2016 8:26   5/2/2016 8:26
82883   D1225,D1256 other2  36.48   5/2/2016 8:28   5/2/2016 8:28
```

what i want is

```
82922   D1292  other2   36.03   5/2/2016 8:18   5/2/2016 8:18
82922   D1132  other2   36.03   5/2/2016 8:18   5/2/2016 8:18
```

Comment: This is not a best way to store the values in DB, better normalise the DB first otherwise you run into troubles in the future

Comment: @Thamilan - looks like that's exactly what the poster is wanting to do

Comment: you want do this in directly in mysql  or using php ?

Comment: ask google 'Mysql split column string into rows'

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
    $rows[$id] = current(explode(',', $row['Epfno']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get resolve this.. create a generic procedure like below and use that to convert comma separated string into rows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_split_string_into_rows`(in string_value varchar(2056))
BEGIN    

    -- Temporary table to hold splited row value of string
    drop temporary table if exists temp_convert;
    create temporary table temp_convert(split_data varchar(2056) );

    -- dynamic query to break comma separated string as rows and insert into column
    set @sql = concat("
                        insert into temp_convert (split_data) 
                        values ('", replace(
                                                ( select group_concat(string_value) as converted_data), ",", "'),('"),"'
                                            );"
                                );
    prepare stmt1 from @sql;
    execute stmt1;

END
```

after that use that procedure in your insert query by calling them :-)